# Arduino LCD Digital Input Counter

Tags: arduino

I currently have an arduino LCD and one SPDT switch connected to my board. The the common pin of the SPDT is grounded and the outer pins are each connected to a digital input. My program should increment and decrement the counter being printed to the LCD screen. I have one input working that increments the counter I do not know how to implement code for the input to decrement the counter. Code posted below.

Thank you

```
 #include <LiquidCrystal.h>


 LiquidCrystal lcd(12, 11, 5,4,3,2); 


 const byte buttonPin = 8;    
 int counter = 0;             // set your counter to zero to begin with


 byte buttonState;             // the current reading from the input pin
 byte lastButtonState = HIGH;   // the previous reading from the input pin

 unsigned long lastDebounceTime = 0;  
 unsigned long debounceDelay = 50;   
 void setup() 
 {
 Serial.begin(9600);  
 pinMode(buttonPin, INPUT_PULLUP); 
 lcd.begin(16, 2);           //  for 2x16 lcd display
 }
 void loop() {
 // read the state of the switch into a local variable:
 byte reading = digitalRead(buttonPin);

 // check to see if you just pressed the button
 // (i.e. the input went from HIGH to LOW),  and you've waited
 // long enough since the last press to ignore any noise:

 // If the switch changed, due to noise or pressing:
 if (reading != lastButtonState) {
  // reset the debouncing timer
  lastDebounceTime = millis();
  }

  if ((millis() - lastDebounceTime) >= debounceDelay) {
  // whatever the reading is at, it's been there for longer
  // than the debounce delay, so take it as the actual current state:

    // if the button state has changed:
    if (reading != buttonState) {
    buttonState = reading;


   if (buttonState == LOW) {   
    counter ++;
    Serial.println(counter);  
    lcd.setCursor(0, 1);
    lcd.print(counter);
  }


  }
 }
 lastButtonState = reading;
  }
```

Comment: Why would the code differ from this, except in pin and direction of counter?

Comment: How would I make this sketch count down, since it's an SPDT switch it is attached to two inputs. It cannot be attached to one input.

Comment: Is that even C++, or just Arduino?

Answer (score 2):

You cannot simply connect one pole of a switch to an input pin an other to the ground. This will detect LOW but when when you are suppose to detect HIGH on the pin, it will be floating. Connect a pull-up resistor to your input pins.

Or you can use pinMode(InPin, INPUT_PULLUP);

This will pull your input pin to high internally and then you can detect the swithces and implememnt the code.

Comment: It's a 3 prong switch, center pin connected to ground, one outside pole connected to digital 8 and the other outside pole connected to digital 9.

Comment: Then while declaring it as an input dont use pinMode(8, INPUT), but use pinMode(8, INPUT_PULLUP). Ans same for the 9th pin.

Comment: Why do you need it connected to two pins? If it is not connected to 8 it's connected to 9...